# JSF 2.0 + Ajax with PrimeFaces 3.5 not working

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am having some problems and couldn't figure them out after 3 days of search. I am using JSF + PrimeFaces 3.5 + Ajax and it is not working correctly.

Basically I have a startDate and numberOfDays attributes. I want to calculate endDate automatically using ajax when both startDate and numberOfDays are informed.

These are the problems:

- It is not updating the attribute endDate. The listener is called (I've breakpointed it!) and the attribute is calculated for sure.
- The listener is called just once. I can't make it run twice!

This is my xhtml page:

```
<div>
    <h:outputLabel for="startDate">
        <h:outputFormat value="startDate" />
        <h:inputText id="startDate" value="#{bean.startDate}">
            <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
        </h:inputText>
    </h:outputLabel>
</div>

<div>
    <h:outputLabel for="numberOfDays">
        <h:outputFormat value="numberOfDays" />
        <h:inputText id="numberOfDays" value="#{bean.numberOfDays}">
            <p:ajax listener="#{bean.calculateEndDate}" process="startDate,numberOfDays" update="panelGroupEndDate" partialSubmit="true" />
        </h:inputText>
    </h:outputLabel>
</div>

<div>
    <h:panelGroup id="panelGroupEndDate">
        <h:outputLabel for="endDate">
            <h:outputFormat value="endDate" />
            <h:inputText id="endDate" value="#{bean.endDate}">
                <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
            </h:inputText>
        </h:outputLabel>
    </h:panelGroup>
</div>
```

Here is my Managed Bean

```
public void calculateEndDate()
{
    if(startDate != null && numberOfDays != null)
    {
        endDate = Util.calculateEndDate(startDate, numberOfDays);
    }
    else
    {
        endDate = null;
    }
}
```

I have ajax codes running in different pages without a problem but all these codes are triggered by a commandButton. These same example works if I use a commandButton to trigger the listener.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanx a lot! :)

Comment: Just want to let you know it works in PF4, I expect the dates are of type Date and numberOfDays is an Integer on the bean, and all getters / setters are there. So probably specific to 3.5, or the problem is outside of this code. Or Util.calculateEndDate throws an exception. Does 3.5 need calculateEndDate(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) ?

Answer (score -1):

Check this out:

```
<p:ajax listener="#{bean.calculateEndDate}" process="startDate,numberOfDays, @this" update="panelGroupEndDate" />
```

I have faced the problem that the listener method is not called, sometimes adding @this to the end of process can make it right.